# Choosing values from rdflib

Tags: python, rdflib

i am new to rdflib and i am using it to run queries on a simple turtle file the data that i am parsing is as follows

`<http://www.siemens.com/ai/plant/data/PolishingStation1> a ns1:Station a ns1:MaterialFlowObject;
    ns1:hasName "PolishingStation1" .
<http://www.siemens.com/ai/plant/data/PolishingStation2> a ns1:Station a ns1:MaterialFlowObject;
    ns1:hasName "PolishingStation2" .
<http://www.siemens.com/ai/plant/data/QuenchingStation1> a ns1:Station a ns1:MaterialFlowObject;
    ns1:hasName "QuenchingStation1" .
<http://www.siemens.com/ai/plant/data/QuenchingStation2> a ns1:Station a ns1:MaterialFlowObject;
    ns1:hasName "QuenchingStation2" .
<http://www.siemens.com/ai/plant/data/QuenchingStation3> a ns1:Station a ns1:MaterialFlowObject;
    ns1:hasName "QuenchingStation3" .
<http://www.siemens.com/ai/plant/data/QuenchingStation4> a ns1:Station a ns1:MaterialFlowObject;
    ns1:hasName "QuenchingStation4" .`

and the query is as follows

`SELECT  ?name ?type
From  
WHERE 
{

```
?MaterialFlowObject a ns1:Drain.
?MaterialFlowObject a ?type.
?MaterialFlowObject ns1:hasName ?name.
#?Parameter ns1:hasParameter    ?parameters .
```

}`

the problem is when i get the type i get 2 values per variable and i cannot separate them at all, the code that i am using

`kg = ConjunctiveGraph()`
 `input_ontology_path = "./plant_data.ttl"`
 `kg.parse(input_ontology_path, format="ttl")`

`with open("queries/get_Material_Flow.rq") as f:`
         `sparql_query_string = f.read()`
         `query_output = kg.query(sparql_query_string)`
         `for row in query_output:`
            `d = str( (row['type'] ))`
           `s = d.split('#')[-1]`
           `print(s)`
            `# pprint.pprint(row)`

The result that i am getting is always a string containing both values
Drain
MaterialFlowObject
in one string and i cannot separate them with split string or anything else, all i need is to get `Drain` in a variable different from `MaterialFlowObject` is there anyway

Comment: Your SPARQL refers to `machines.ttl`, but you're also parsing `plant_data.ttl` in your script. Your query refers to `ns1:Drain`, but your data uses `ns1:Station`. Your files use, but do not define, an `ns1:` prefix. Please post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

With your sample files fixed up:

`plant_data.ttl`:

```
@prefix ns1: <tag:a#> .

<http://www.siemens.com/ai/plant/data/PolishingStation1>
    a ns1:Station;
    a ns1:MaterialFlowObject;
    ns1:hasName "PolishingStation1" .
...
```

`get_Material_Flow.rq`:

```
PREFIX ns1: <tag:a#>

SELECT ?name ?type 
WHERE {
  ?MaterialFlowObject a ns1:Station.
  ?MaterialFlowObject a ?type.
  ?MaterialFlowObject ns1:hasName ?name.
}
```

`run_query.py`:

```
from rdflib.graph import ConjunctiveGraph

kg = ConjunctiveGraph() 
input_ontology_path = "./plant_data.ttl" 
kg.parse(input_ontology_path, format="ttl")

with open("get_Material_Flow.rq") as f:
    sparql_query_string = f.read() 
    query_output = kg.query(sparql_query_string) 
    for row in query_output: 
        print(f'name={str(row["name"])},type={str(row["type"])}')
```

This works as expected, and produces a result for each match:

```
name=PolishingStation1,type=tag:a#Station
name=PolishingStation1,type=tag:a#MaterialFlowObject
name=QuenchingStation3,type=tag:a#MaterialFlowObject
name=QuenchingStation3,type=tag:a#Station
name=QuenchingStation4,type=tag:a#Station
name=QuenchingStation4,type=tag:a#MaterialFlowObject
name=PolishingStation2,type=tag:a#MaterialFlowObject
name=PolishingStation2,type=tag:a#Station
name=QuenchingStation2,type=tag:a#MaterialFlowObject
name=QuenchingStation2,type=tag:a#Station
name=QuenchingStation1,type=tag:a#MaterialFlowObject
name=QuenchingStation1,type=tag:a#Station
```